# Pre Render Master Pages and ViewState

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, viewstate, prerender

There is some viewstate stuff going on in the codebehind and then there is an update panel. When I add this into a child page referenced by a master page it breaks all the previously working functionality I had before from my user controls.

child to master page code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GetBrands();
            GetStyles();
            GetColors();
            this.BindItemsList();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { }
}
```

Comment: show some code and is any of this in a `updatepanel`?

Comment: There is a lot of code. But the viewstate is all in an update panel but the other stuff isn't. its in a web control put into a master page and the viewstate is loaded in froma  child page into the master page. THanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `UpdatePannel`. If this fixes your code, you will have isolated the issue to your implementation around `ViewState`. Issues with `UpdatePannels` and `ViewState` are not uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

PreRender fires after control events are handled. Any control added during PreRender will by ignore all control related events.

I can't tell if this is possibly the cause of your issue since you haven't provided any code but you might try performing your logic in PageLoad instead.

PreRender is a good place to modify control appearances or add non-event related markup.

Answer (score -1):

You need to override CreateChildControls methods of you master page and populate controls in this method. This method should be used to create child controls in code behind class of the pages and server controls. This should to resolve problem that Viewstate is not restored for populated controls. Also, sometimes problem with Viewstate restoring can be in how you add your controls in PopulateControls method. You should to ensure that at first containers controls (like panel or etc) is added to controls collection and only then controls are added to this containers.

At any case you need to try something like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Called by the ASP.NET page framework to notify server controls that use composition-based 
/// implementation to create any child controls they contain in preparation for posting back or rendering.
/// </summary>
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    base.CreateChildControls();
    PopulateControls();
}
```

Comment: CreateChildControls() is a method on Control not on Page or MasterPage. I think you are confusing the questioner's PopulateControls() method with similar names in the framework.

Comment: MasterPage is inheritted from UserControl class. So, MasterPage and Page class supports  CreateChildControls method. You can check this in MSDN or simpy try to override this method. This is link to MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.masterpage.aspx

Comment: @andleer You are not correct at all. MasterPage has CreateChildControls method.

Comment: @maxim should CreateChildControls() be called from codebehind of masterpage or user control? If master page, I am having trouble that route creating the contentplaceholder and finding the controls (they are all null at that point). Which would be easier modifying the page lifecycle calls or just getting rid of the update panel?

Comment: @user694071 Could you please specify what your populate method does. Does it creates any controls dynamically (from server side). Do you create any other controls dynamically?

Comment: It has something to do with viewstate and the update panel. They a. do not function when I add a masterpage to their aspx and b. they break existing functionality. I.e. if I add to cart the page does not update correctly.

Comment: @user694071 I reviewed your code and don't see problem. I have only suggestion that you try to call databinding (not only during initial page load when Page.IsPostBack equals to false) to check if this will resolve problem. If this will resolve your problem than the cause of the problem is that controls collection which are created during postback is not the same as it was during initial page load.